# Chakra with Next13: useColorModeValue) is not a function

Tags: next.js13, chakra-ui

So I use Chakra in my Nextjs 13 project, I have this code:

```
const Home = () => {
  const color = useColorModeValue("telegram.500", "telegram.400");

  return <div>something here</div>
}
```

I get this error: `Error: (0 , _chakra_ui_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useColorModeValue) is not a function`

Here is some info:

```
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have imported it as default.

You should import as:

```
import {useColorModeValue}  from "@chakra-ui/react";
```

not

```
import useColorModeValue  from "@chakra-ui/react";
```